# How to check if a cell has a specific character in specific position in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

df:

```
uid          maskeduid
VEH12345L0    72647hghghghg
VEH12323L3    hgh5454jjbjjb
VEH11145M4    jhj24j3j5bjnj
VEH78345L3    12kjkkndw2knk
VEH31345N3n   145jhjhjbvrkl
```

I want to get a dataframe df1 where 9th character of every cell ='L'

df1:

```
 uid          maskeduid
VEH12345L0    72647hghghghg
VEH12323L3    hgh5454jjbjjb
VEH78345L3    12kjkkndw2knk
```

How can I achieve by using any pandas in built function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python counts from `0`, so for select `9th` values use `str[8]`, compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with `L` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['uid'].str[8].eq('L')]
print (df1)
          uid      maskeduid
0  VEH12345L0  72647hghghghg
1  VEH12323L3  hgh5454jjbjjb
3  VEH78345L3  12kjkkndw2knk
```